# Proper use of ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, automatic-ref-counting

While creating properties, is it correct to replace all `retains` with `strong`, and all `assigns` with `weak`?

I'm switching to ARC any helpful tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html)

Use Xcode's guide: Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC.

At first, it may report various issues( in the precheck building phase), just try fixing all issues, try again and (build and fail )again, and it would be done mostly smoothly in the end when all issues are fixed, leaving your code with ARC.

Note that the pre-checking rules are more tough than usual build settings.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `strong` and `retain` are synonyms, so they do *exactly* the same.
*Edit: Also `unsafe_unretained` is synonym for `assign`, as* nielsbot *pointed out.*

Then the `weak` is almost like `assign`, but automatically set to nil after the object, it is pointing to, is deallocated.

**That means, you can simply replace them.**

However, there is one special case I've encountered, where I had to use `assign`, rather than `weak`. Let's say we have two properties `delegateAssign` and `delegateWeak`. In both is stored our delegate, that is owning us by having the only strong reference. The delegate is deallocating, so our `-dealloc` method is called too.

```
// Our delegate is deallocating and there is no other strong ref.
- (void)dealloc {
    [delegateWeak doSomething];
    [delegateAssign doSomething];
}
```

The delegate is already in deallocation process, but still not fully deallocated. The problem is that **`weak` references to him are already nullified!** Property `delegateWeak` contains nil, but `delegateAssign` contains valid object (with all properties already released and nullified, but still valid).

```
// Our delegate is deallocating and there is no other strong ref.
- (void)dealloc {
    [delegateWeak doSomething]; // Does nothing, already nil.
    [delegateAssign doSomething]; // Successful call.
}
```

It is quite special case, but it reveal us how those `weak` variables work and when they are nullified.

Comment: I think `assign` and `unsafe_unretained` are equivalent under ARC

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes. `strong` is the ARC equivalent of `retain`, and `weak` is the equivalent of `assign`, only it is also zeroing (sets the pointer to `nil` if the object is deallocated, preventing potential `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crashes), so it is even better than `assign`. The [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html) page, as already mentioned, provides more details if you're interested.

Comment: weak is not quite the equivalent of assign. unsafe_unretained is the equivalent. weak is in fact, a new feature that requires run-time support (iOS5/OSX10.6 upwards). . The difference is that weak will be automatically set to nil when the object goes away, whereas assign/unsafe_unretained can leave a dangling pointer.

Comment: What the hell, I just commented a really old question. How the hell did I end up here? I thought I clicked on unanswered. . . ARC was new back then, no doubt you know all this now. . . worth mentioning tho.